# How many entries into this contest before a win is guaranteed.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I thought of a sort of "game" that illustrates a situation where a person's probability of "winning" ranges from 0 to 1. I'm sure there's a name for it, or a better way to put it, but anyway, it goes like this:

There are N entries allowed in a contest. Every time someone submits an entry, one of the existing entries is swapped out (at random) and the new entry is added. Each person can submit more than 1 entry, but only 1 at a time. There's a glitch in the system where all the entries are in and ready to pull, but Tom, who currently has no entries in the contest, is still allowed to submit. **What is the average number of times Tom has to submit to ensure all of the entries are his, resulting in a 100% chance of winning?**

Obviously, if Tom submits 0 entries, he has a 0% chance of winning. The entries are swapped out at random, so he will at least have to submit 100 entries; however, every time he submits he might swap out an entry he already has. If he keeps swapping one of his entries for a new one of his entries, he stays at a 1/N probability of winning no matter how many entries he submits. So obviously the expected value of number of turns to guaranty a win ranges from 100 to Infinity.

For N=100, the average appears to be ~520, which I determined empirically. I am looking for a mathematical way to determine what this average, expected value would be based on N.

```
For various values of N:
N      Apparent Ave
10     29
50     220
100    520
500    3360
800    5820
```

I scripted up a little R code to determine what the value might be, and that should help illustrate what I'm asking. Obviously not going for code-golf here.

```
tres <- 1000
ress <- vector("numeric",tres)
bigN <- 100
for (i in seq_along(ress)){
  sdf <- rep(0,bigN)
  counts <- 0
  while (any(sdf==0)) {
    sdf[sample(length(sdf),1)]<-1
    counts=counts+1
  }
  ress[i] <- counts
}
summary(ress)
```

Comment: This is also known as coupon collector's problem

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) will tell you the result is $n \sum\limits_1^n \frac1k \approx n \log_e(n) + 0.5572\ldots n + \frac12-\frac{1}{12n}+\cdots$

Comment: @Henry Thanks! And thanks for the redirect.